# How do I test a user receiving a text?

Tags: unit-testing, functional-testing

I am writing functional tests for my application that scrapes some data online then sends the results in an SMS text (on a weekly basis). My understanding is that functional tests are meant to test the functionality from the users' point of view. So, how do I "test" that the user receives a text? I am using Twilio API. Also, how do I test that the user is receiving the text weekly? Am I thinking about this wrong?

Comment: How would you test this manually ?

Comment: Add a unit test to send a text to my personal number... then I read it. However, if I automated that completely, wouldn't I need to have 2 Twilio instances communicating with each other (one receiving and one sending)? Is that a redudant test? Right now I'm just focusing on the string format itself.

Comment: It depends on how critical this formatting question is. 2 Twilio instances are not enough. Phones will have different formatting, different default fonts, and custom fonts on top of that. So maybe a more useful test would be to check whether Twilio say they’re happy with your sending request, and assert on their response.

Comment: @SteveChamaillard thanks, I'll try that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're using a third-party API, so you don't need to spend a lot of effort to automate testing the functionality provided by that API. You need to focus testing on your application's interactions with that API.

One set of tests can be written against the API documentation. Looking at the documentation, what are the valid responses from the API? If you mock out the third-party API and replace it with mock responses, does your system behave as expected given the response?

Another set of tests can used captured actual responses from the API and ensure that your system is handling the actual messages. You could combine this with the first approach, as well and capture real responses in different sets of success and failure cases and use those in testing.

Some APIs also have test credentials. [It appears that Twilo provides this.](https://www.twilio.com/docs/iam/test-credentials) In some cases, they may have different, test-specific endpoints that they maintain to allow you to test different scenarios and get simulated responses. This can also be useful in test or other demonstration environments.

You should have monitoring and logging (of the parameters to and responses from) the third-party API. You can perform some manual testing in a pre-production environment, probably using the test credentials. Monitoring in the production environment can also provide information to report defects to the vendor.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I will try this out!

Comment: I will like to add that some end-to-end tests for Twilio are warranted, but they should verify *environmental configurations* rather than application logic. You still want to make sure all the bits and pieces are connected properly in each environment. These tests are best done manually as needed.

Comment: You absolutely have to test your use of third-party APIs. You are responsible for the whole system. If you pass a wrong flag to that system telling it to skip invalid phone numbers, and your system mangles phone numbers, the API says it's okay but you still have to fix that. Even if the API has a *bug* you have to work around the bug or make the vendor fix it - you're still responsible.

Comment: @DocBrown In my experience, the third-party vendors don't need reproducible tests. Specific logs are often enough to report defects. Saying that at a specific time a specific set of arguments were passed to the API and the unexpected behavior happened is often enough. I've added logging and monitoring into the answer. Monitoring can alert the team on these unexpected events so they can examine the logs to debug their application or to communicate with the vendor.

Comment: @user253751 I agree that you need to test your use of the API, and that's exactly what I'm arguing for. Your examples are things that I would expect your tests to identify. If the API requires data to be in a specific format, you would have code that formats that data properly and tests over that data. Tests on what you pass to the API, receive from the API, and some manual testing would be sufficient.

Comment: I think your final edit has improved the answer heavily.